# Need help selecting non-empty column values from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a MySQL table which has about 30 columns. One column has empty values for the majority of the table. How can I use a MySQL command to filter out the items which do have values in the table?

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column IS NOT NULL
```

This does not filter because I have empty cells rather that having `NULL` in the void cell.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Also look for the columns not equal to the empty string `''`

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND column <> ''
```

If you have fields containing only whitespace which you consider empty, use `TRIM()` to eliminate the whitespace, and potentially leave the empty string `''`

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column) <> ''
```

Comment: This worked really well for me - especially the TRIM() version. Thanks.

Comment: How can we use this in query instead of rawquery (android sqliteopenhelper)?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column = "" worked for me

Answer (score 11):

A alternate approach that also handles blank spaces in a column as well as null:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE TRIM(column) > ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes seems the value from a field is empty but the query filter ignores and still shows the result with empty fields.
From my experience I recommend a trick:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND CONCAT_WS(",",TRIM(column),TRIM(column)) <> ','
```

Very weird approach but works 100%!!

MySql says in documentation that

> column IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column) <> ''

will work but this does not happen always, trust me!!